# Use Conditional Split for multiple empty string

Tags: ssis

I have a scenario where I am generating two .CSV files from one .TXT file source.

One of the transformations required is this:

- Identify records that contain at least one field with an empty string or NULL value
- Send these records to a separate .CSV file destination

I need to check for this condition across multiple fields.

For example I have these fields in my source .TXT file:

```
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5
col6 
col7
```

I need to check to see if any of these fields contain an empty string or a NULL value.

I am using a Conditional Split Transformation with this formula:

```
col1 !=""
```

That works as expected for one column, but not as expected when I try to write the formula for all columns in my text file:

```
col1 !="" || col2 !=""...
```

Some rows with an empty or NULL value in one of the fields are ending up in the wrong .CSV file.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Empty and null are not the same thing. What do you mean by it doesn't evaluate the condition? do you receive an error message?

Comment: No, It runs successfully with all rows in the file but doesn't evaluates the condition and split the record in other file.

Comment: It could be that the cols are not empty but have whitespaces; try trimming the cols, e.g. TRIM(col1)!="" || TRIM(col1)!="" || ...

Comment: There is no spaces because its a test file and intentionally kept some of the filed values blank to test.

Answer (score 4):

If I have understood your question correctly, I think you just need to use the following formula in a Conditional Split Transformation:

```
ISNULL(col1) || ISNULL(col2) || ISNULL(col3) || ISNULL(col4) || ISNULL(col5) || ISNULL(col6) || ISNULL(col7) || TRIM(col1) == "" || TRIM(col2) == "" || TRIM(col3) == "" || TRIM(col4) == "" || TRIM(col5) == "" || TRIM(col6) == "" || TRIM(col7) == ""
```

There is a difference between an empty string and a NULL, although since your source is a .TXT file this might not be so obvious as it would be if your source was a database table.

[Here is the SQL Fiddle for the sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad7f9/2).

Screenshot of the Conditional Split Transformation Editor

[image: Screenshot of the Conditional Split Transformation Editor]

Screenshot of the Data Flow results

[image: Screenshot of the Data Flow results]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But as my source is flat file (.txt).

Comment: You are welcome. The concept and formula are the same: use a "Flat File Source" instead of an "OLE DB Source". I am using the "OLE DB Source" simply to highlight the differences between an empty string and a NULL.

Comment: I tried every possible ways, even the one that you mentioned but no success. I think I have to go for staging table approach.

Comment: Might be your best option. Sometimes the best use of SSIS is to simply get your data into a database table and then manipulate it as you need to from there. If you want to post some same data from your actual file (a misdirected row for example) we might be able to help more. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

**I Figured it out. Used script component before conditional split to flag the rows.**

Code:

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
/**string RecordID = "";
string ClientRequestID = "";
string AccountID = "";
string ClientMemberID = "";
string MemberDOB = "";
string ProviderPhone = "";**/
string Flag = "True";

public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    if (Row.ClientRequestID == "" || Row.ClientMemberID == "" || Row.AccountID == "" || Row.MemberDOB == "" || Row.ProviderPhone == "")
    {

        Flag = "False";
    }
    else
    {
        Flag = "True";
    }
    Row.Flag = Flag;
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look carefully at your expression in your script and your expression in your original example. Do you see the difference? One uses `!=` and the other uses `==`. These are different logical expressions. Your original approach probably would have worked if you got the logical expression correct.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - you are right. But I am flagging those rows as false and passing only true in conditional split as you can see that. which resolved my issue.

Comment: They are totally different different boolean expressions. `Col1 != "" || Col2 != ""` works totally differently to `Col1 = "" || Col2 = ""`. If you flip around the result you get different answers - try it and see.